# Erroneous Result in Getting response using HTTPClient(JSONParser) in Android

Tags: android, json, http

I am trying to use the JSONParser Library to get response in the form of JSON.
However, I used this code to get response from 2 urls sequentially (After getting one response I start the other) but in my second request I am getting the same response(JSON) as the first one although I am hitting a different URL.Is there any way to flush/clear the httpEntity/httpClient/httpget/httpResponse .

```
 DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
            httpget.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpget);
            HttpEntity httpEntity= httpResponse.getEntity();

            is = httpEntity.getContent();
```

Note: When I run them independently , they run just fine.

Comment: Can you provide more of your code? Here you are just creating one request and what you are doing here is legit. Which way do you use to execute the second request?

Comment: I use async tasks for getting the json results i.e after one async task is complete I call another activity from its onPostExecute method and in that activity I start another async task which downloads the second json.

Comment: This doesn't explain the described behaviour. However, I've overseen one detail in your code. What is the `is` variable? Is it a class variable. And furthermore why you init a new activity to start another AsyncTask?